# How to make a cool looking layout for menu in python 3.2?

Tags: command-line, python-3.2

I have created a menu for a class and, I'm hoping that I can find out how to achieve a cool look for it. This program is command line based, not GUI.

The only way that I can figure this out is to do something silly like:

```
print(' ------------------------')
print('|                        |')
print('|                        |')
print('|                        |')
print('|                        |')
print('|                        |')
print(' ------------------------')
```

I would like for all of the lines to actually connect.
My menu would be inside of this box. I hope I have given enough information.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: As someone who has wasted hours doing stuff like this in undergraduate school, let me just say that if you don't get graded on how nice your program looks, then I wouldn't worry about adding the lines.  I would just add a simple looking ordered list.

Comment: For a mediocre grade I can do just that, but for an outstanding grade I must go above and beyond. =/ I just want to get my A and not have something that looks like everyone else

Comment: Ah, well then it will be worth doing... Do you have to create a command line application?  Building a GUI would look nicer and actually be time well spent on improving the quality of your application.

Comment: No GUI. It is only executed on the command line. She will gig points if we don't follow instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may like http://tuxradar.com/content/code-project-build-ncurses-ui-python or http://excess.org/urwid/examples.html :-)